# Java performance - good practices (using references)

Tags: java

This is the basic structure of code on a project I am contributing to:

```
protected ModelAndView showForm(ActionContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Command cmd = ctx.getCommand();
    SubCommand subCmd = cmd.getSubCommand();
    doSmth(cmd, subCmd);
    doSmthElse(ctx);
    doSmthElse2(ctx);
}
```

and every `doSmthElse(ctx)` begins with

```
Command cmd = ctx.getCommand();
SubCommand subCmd = cmd.getSubCommand();
```

for me it is NOT clear why it looks like this and it should be changed towards the way it looks in doSmth. Please correct me if i'm wrong, but i think it also works slower as it is now.

Comment: without sharing code behing getCommand and getSubCommand we cant be sure. It may be fine if its just value return.

Comment: it returns a reference to a big object (~150 variable big bean)

Comment: If it's just a getter, I doubt this is a performance problem - especially in the context of web. If you have a readability problem, sure - refactor.

Comment: Agree with @vikingsteve, this should not make any BIG difference as far as performance is concerned.

Comment: Perfomance-wise, this is clearly a non-issue. Furthermore, refactoring means you give less freedom to the methods: that may be good (constraining the possible kinds of stuff they do) or bad (making certain internal changes to the methods impossible without changing their signatures).

Comment: thx for your comments. for me it was a readability issue + i thought that it may a performance issue. if i cant use 'performance' argument - others are not sufficient :)
thx anyway, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getCommand` is as simple as `return command;` then there won't be any performance difference.

From a design perspective, if `doSmthElse` only needs the sub command to do its work, then you could indeed pass what it needs and only what it needs rather than a "generic" context object that contains unnecessary information - it will allow easier testing too. If that is the case, it would make sense to call `doSmthElse(subCmd)`.

But that will mean that if you need more information at a later stage you will need to change the method signature.

In other words, as often, it depends...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the major point is not *performance* per se, but it's a conceptual/clarity thing. If the commands and subcommands always go together, then it makes more sense to replace `doSmth(cmd, subCmd)` with `doSmth(ctx)`.

Regarding performance, if the object is prebuilt (that is, it doesn't get rebuilt on a getter call), it does not matter how many references to it there are.